# Windows 8.1 power plans: No password prompt when monitor wakes but password prompt when PC wakes

Tags: display, windows-8.1, passwords, sleep

Is it possible to get Windows 8.1 to not ask for a password when the monitor comes out of power saving mode, but still ask for a password when the PC wakes from sleeping?

Setting the "Turn off the display" in Control Panel / Power Options (same as "PC and devices" / "Power and sleep" in the Metro view) puts the monitor into power saving mode after a period of inactivity as required, but I'm prompted for a password when the monitor is reactivated.

Setting "Require a password on wake-up" to "No" in the  advanced power settings rectifies this, but then it also won't ask for a password when the PC is woken from sleeping.

I think I must be missing something, because this was a pretty easy configuration in Windows 7.

I have no screen-saver configured.

**EDIT**

I'm reluctant to change to another power plan, as my machine is currently set up on a custom overclocked power plan and I don't know the implications of changing to another plan. Is it possible to achieve the above within my existing plan? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Open the Control Panel and go to the **Power Options**.
Choose **Change plan settings** and click **Change advanced power settings**.

Open the **Change advanced power settings** and select "High performance", "Balanced" or "Power saver".
There you find a password reaction. I don't now how named this option in English. I have the German version installed.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I've looked more into power plans and have realised that mine is configured to use a custom overclocked plan. I'm reluctant to change plans, as I'm not sure about the implications. Is it possible for me to change the settings related to the monitor within the existing plan?

Comment: Hi. Yes, you can change the existing plan without problems.